# Own Error page with Nginx won't work

Tags: nginx

I want to create own error files. But I always see a white site with "File not found". I have checked it in the PHP location with the same result.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name mydomain.com;

    ssl_.........

    root /var/www/html/mydomain.com;
    .....

    error_page 404 /404.php;
    location = /404.php {
        root /var/www/html/mydomain.com/errorpage;
        internal;
    }

    location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        default_type text/plain;
        root /var/www/letsencrypt;
    }

    location / {
        index index.php;

        try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
    }

    location @rewrite {
        rewrite ^/(site/|contact/)?([^.]+)$ /$1index.php?$2 last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/mydomain.com-php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        proxy_connect_timeout 900;
        proxy_send_timeout 900;
        proxy_read_timeout 900;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 900;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 900;
    }

    .....
}
```

I have found many tips with:

```
fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
```

And other lines. But no chance.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a step solution.

```
error_page 404 /404.php;
location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/mydomain.com-php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        proxy_connect_timeout 900;
        proxy_send_timeout 900;
        proxy_read_timeout 900;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 900;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 900;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    }
```

This will work when the 404.php is in the main directory.
When I add this

```
location = /404.php {
        root /var/www/html/mydomain.com/errorpage;
        internal;
    }
```

The 404.php will found, but it goes not into php parser and give me to download the 404.php

Have you an idea how can I fix it?